# C++ chrono literals allow you assign say 10d, how does it not generate a syntax error

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

```cpp
constexpr auto day = 14d;`
```

How is that line not generating a syntax error?

I see something like the following in Microsoft's documentation ..

```cpp
constexpr std::chrono::day operator"" d(unsigned long long d) noexcept;
```

I have searched for `operator""` but no hits.

I try not to use any syntax I don’t understand. Most of C++ goes over my head

Look forward to some insight.

Comment: You can read about [`std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""d`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22d) on Cppreference.

Comment: The thing to search for is "User-defined literals". https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Comment: _I have searched for operator"" but no hits._ That's because Google treats quotes in a special way when searching, rather than searching for the quotes as-is.  I don't know a workaround for this, sorry.